# FormArray Pagination

Tags: angular, angular-forms

i have a formArray :

```
this.tableRules = this._fb.group({
  rules: this._fb.array([])
});

  get rulesArray(){
    let rules = this.tableRules.get('rules') as FormArray;
    return rules;
  }
```

i want to paginate using pipe which i have created below Unable to understand on how i can implement it :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Rule } from './rule';
import { FormArray, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Pipe({
  name: 'pagination',
  pure:false
})
export class PaginationPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: FormArray, pageSize : string , pageNumber : string): any {
    let startIndex = (parseInt(pageNumber)- 1) * parseInt(pageSize);
    let endIndex = startIndex + parseInt(pageSize);
    return value;
  }

}
```

in my html i've used this way :

```
<div formArrayName="rules" *ngFor="let rule of rulesArray.controls | pagination : '10' : '1'; let i = index;">
```

Any help appreciated . 
Thanks

Comment: Instead of pipe. please move the pagination logic to child component. Share the formarray as @Input and start, endindex as INput and Event Emitter

Comment: why do you  want to paginate form?

Comment: form is in the table . each element of form array is my table row @Chellappan

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya can you provide an example ?

Comment: You might want to create a stackblitz sample.

Comment: In an FormArray you have two things: formArrayName, and formGroupName (I supouse you can work using [formGroupName]="10*pageno+i" into a *ngFor="let i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]>